# How to automatically shut down a minecraft bungeecord server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

I have a minecraft 1.17.1 spigot bungeecord server that consists of the bungeecord server itself and seven regular servers. Currently, I have a start.sh file in the main directory that starts each server in a different screen window:

```
//For each server
screen server1 sudo java -Xmx4G -Xms1G spigot-1.17.1.jar
```

However, in order to shut it down, I have to manually open each server console and type the stop command. Ending each screen, like the following:

```
screen -r server1 quit
```

is not an option for me to do, as it potentially leads to loss of server information. Is there either a better way of shutting it down, maybe something that enacts the stop command on each server at the same time?

Comment: Why are you running Java with root privileges? I had a basic look into Bungeecord and didn't see a need for it. You shouldn't use sudo unnecessarily like this, because a successful exploit can now do *anything* on your server. Without `sudo`, a successful exploit will only be able to do whatever the user account running the server can do, which ideally is only what is needed to actually run the server, nothing more.

Comment: For some reason java threw a bunch of errors when sudo was not used.

Comment: What were this errors? I'm a year late! :P